# Is possible CanCan can :manage, :all except one or more method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm doing:

```
can :manage, :all if user.role == 'admin'

can :approve, Anuncio do |anuncio|
  anuncio.try(:aprovado) == false
end
```

My second method does not work because the :manage :all override it.
Theres a way to declare can manage all except approve? and inside approve i just do

```
can :approve, Anuncio do |anuncio|
  user.role == 'admin' && anuncio.try(:aprovado) == false
end
```

What's the better solution?

Comment: Ruby en los Carriles :')

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try do it another way round, look into [cancan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#combining-abilities). Try:

```
can :manage, :all if user.role == 'admin'

cannot :approve, Anuncio do |anuncio|
  anuncio.try(:aprovado)
end
```

Comment: I should pay more attention into the wiki, thanks a lot for answer! =)

Comment: unfortunately i can't vote up because as i'm new here in stackoverflow, i haven't enough reputation to do it :/ i need 15 reputation points! lol =)